# Spring passing a bean to another class dynamically

Tags: java, spring

I am new to Spring.
Currently, I am trying to achieve following:

A method in `class A` calls a method in `class B` with a String parameter. `Class B` then creates a bean after processing the string (just doing some basic string operations) as:

```
        GenericApplicationContext context = new GenericApplicationContext();
        DefaultListableBeanFactory factory = (DefaultListableBeanFactory) context.getBeanFactory();

        BeanDefinitionBuilder bean1 = BeanDefinitionBuilder.rootBeanDefinition("className");
        bean1.addPropertyReference("sampleString", "sampleBean");
        bean1.addPropertyValue("sampleString", "processed string here");
        factory.registerBeanDefinition("sampleBean", bean1.getBeanDefinition());
        context.refresh();
```

(I am not sure if my approach to creating bean here is correct. If not, please suggest the appropriate way).

I want this bean to be passed to `class A` (ofcourse the *Spring Way*). The name of variable is `sampleString`.

So far I had been using something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

<bean id="proc" class="A">
</bean>

<bean id="result" class="B">
<property name="sampleString" value="#{proc.sampleString}"/>
</bean>

</beans>
```

But this copies null value to the variable in class A (ofcourse because the method executes only when a button is pressed).

So is there a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: my [impression](http://t.wallpaperweb.org/wallpaper/development/1440x1080/T_Metal_Shavings_0691491_1440x1080.jpg) of Spring

Comment: thats the whole reason I am messing with it. I hate my simple life =.=;

Comment: It's not clear what you're *really* trying to achieve - creating beans dynamically at runtime (especially as a result of user's interaction with a GUI) is not something you'd do normally.